# Shiny dashboard css tabBox

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I would like to add some css (background, remove the padding) in my tabBox containing two tabpanel but nothing seems to appear when I'm adding css at the top of the dashboard body.

[mydashboard tabpanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FtoJ.png)

and here what I want 
[dashboard with correct background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPQ3M.png)

> my code

```
   body < -dashboardBody(
            tags$style(type = "text/css", Errorcss),
            tags$style("
                .nav - tabs - custom > .tab - content {
                    background: #3c8dbc;
        padding: 0px;
            padding-top: 0px;
            padding-right: 0px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
            padding-left: 0px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    }")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide your HTML

Comment: I think the Tabcontent area having **padding**, unset set that. you may get the output

Comment: I removed it and nothing happens

Comment: This question can be closed, I solved it  by modifying directly the css source file and then added it in my app at the top head, with this code includeCSS("./css/AdminLTE.min.css"),